# I can't access database and migrate in laravel project using port number 3306 for mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, vagrant

[The first picture is the database config in .env file and the port number is 3306](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxgXc.png)

[The second picture is the database config in /config/database.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy63k.png)

[The third picture is the database config in mysql workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBxfB.png)

I cannot migrate the model and access database when the port number set to 3306 in .env file, while if set to 33060 it can access.

And it generated error "Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations)" when I try to run "php artisan migrate".

I tried a lot of methods but still encounter the same problem when using port 3306.

Comment: you must set the `DB_HOST` to the IP address through which you can reach your vagran box, check in your `vagrantfile` the `ip_address` is set to which value

Comment: I searched the project directory, found three vagrantfile, but none of them contains "ip_address".

Comment: can you access the vagrant box via terminal?

Comment: yes, I can use vagrant command in terminal like "vagrant up".

Comment: put in your vagrantfile `config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.1.10"` after that run `vagran reload` in terminal

Comment: where should I put it in the file, there are a if statements

Comment: put it on top of the file

Comment: I've solved it, thank you very much.

Comment: Your are welcome, I put the answer as a separate answer for you to mark it as the answer to your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vagrant box will not run on localhost(127.0.0.1) like you specified in your .env file, you must specify the `ip_address` on which you can reach vagrant by putting in your `vagrantfile`

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.1.10"
```

after that run `vagran reload` in terminal